# When does ProcessBuilder.start() returns null instead of an Process object?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.OutputStream java.lang.Process.getOutputStream()' on a null object reference

This is what I try to do:

```
protected void runProc(String[] args) {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start(); // or was it processBuilder
        BufferedWriter stdin = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream())); // stdin
        BufferedReader stdout = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); // stdout
        BufferedReader stderr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream())); // stderr
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I really can't seem to find what I need in the java documentation.
Seems to me that a null object gets returned by the `start()` method.

Any other way I can call the start method?

Comment: Based on discussion below, I have concluded that Jakub was mistaken.  The problem (whatever it was) was not that `start()` was returning `null`.  This is Not Reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

> When does ProcessBuilder.start() returns null ...

According to the javadoc, `start()` does not return `null`.  The javadoc says that it returns a `Process` and doesn't mention returning `null`.  If there was any circumstance in which `start()` *could* return `null`, then that *should* be mentioned explicitly in the javadoc in the "Returns:" for the method.

That is the convention that they follow.

I took a look at the source code for `ProcessBuilder.start()` in Java 11, and by my reading it is actually impossible for the result to be `null`.

The actual code is in a `static Process start()` method that is declared in the package private `ProcessImpl` class.    If that method returns at all, it returns an newly created instance of `ProcessImpl` ... which extends `Process`.

(There are different versions of `ProcessImpl` for Unix and Windows platforms.  I check both versions.)

---

So the question is: how come you are getting that NPE?

My guess is that you are misreading the stacktrace (which you haven't shown us!), and the exception is not being thrown in *that* call to `getOutputStream()`.  Or maybe the compiled code that you are running doesn't match the source code you are looking at.

Either way, we will need **you** to provide a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if we are to take this any further.  A "minrepex" that we can *actually* compile and run, and that *actually* throws an NPE for us to diagnose.

(And for what it is worth, I am disinclined to believe that either the javadocs or the Java SE implementation are incorrect.)

---

> Any other way I can call the `start()` method?

Not that I am aware of.  But that is probably a blind alley.  The real solution will involve figuring out where that NPE is really coming from.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wJbkBxXb

Comment: That is a minrep for a different issue.  You asked about `start()` returning `null`.  If (as I suspect will be the case) you are **unable** to write a minrep for the original issue, update the question to say that you cannot reproduce it ... and we can close it as "not reproducible".

Comment: It went over my head, that the scope of the stdin/stdout/stderr went from global to the class to local to the method.